# About emptiness of a set of holomorphic functions[CSIR-UGC NET]

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $ D $  be the open unit disc in $ \mathbb{C} $ and $ H(D) $ be the collection of all holomorphic functions on it. Let $$ S= [f\in H(D):f(\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2n}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}]$$ and $$ T=[f\in H(D):f(\frac{1}{2n})=f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=\frac{1}{2n} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}]$$.

Then

1. Both are S and T are singleton sets
2. S is a singleton set but T is null
3. T is a singleton set but S is null.
4. Both S and T are empty.

I think the answer is option 2. The partial reason is by using the identity theorem, we obtain set consisting of only a constant function. But, how to prove that T is null? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: $T$ contains all constant functions, so it is neither empty nor a singleton.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks, edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right to invoke the identity principle for $S$; it shows that $f(z)=z$ is the only element of $S$.  After your edit, $T$ is a subset of $S$ (since the defining equation $f(\frac1{2n})=\frac1{2n}$ of $S$ is now included in the definition of $T$) but does not contain the one and only element of $S$, so $T$ is empty.